# Group search results by post type, but having a unique heading for each section?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, search

I've been struggling to make it work. This code works and returns search results separated for each post type, however I would like to have a unique heading for each section and style it, currently it only shows the name of those post type.. not looking pretty and user friendly.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php
// We change the definition of the array to be able to store the count of each post_type
$types = array('post' => 0, 'windows' => 0, 'android' => 0, 'game' => 0, 'web' => 0);
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    // We check that only allowed post_type are counted
    if (array_key_exists(get_post_type(), $types)) {
        $types[get_post_type()]++;
    }
}
?>
<?php foreach ($types AS $type => $nb_of_type) : ?>
    <?php // We only show post_types that have at least one result  ?>
    <?php if ($nb_of_type > 0) : ?>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4><?= $type; ?></h4>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php if (get_post_type() === $type) : ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'archive' ); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else :
        _e( 'Sorry, nothing has been found.' );
    ?>
```